# Format for errors returned in XML API

Tags: xml, web-services, api

I am building an API based on XML messages. On part of it, receives several entities and process them.

Now, in case of a processing error on one of the entities, I want to continue processing the other entities and return errors messages for the ones that were not processed, so the consumer knows which entities were not processed.

What is the best way to return these errors, so that the consumer knows exactly which entities failed and with what error messages?

Here is what a request would look like:

```
<entities>
  <entity>
    <title>first</title>
    <description>short text</description>
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <title>second</title>
    <description>second short text</description>
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <title>third</title>
    <description>third short text</description>
  </entity>
</entities>
```

Now let's suppose the first and the third entity generate errors. How could the response look like?

Comment: their xpath i suppose? entities/entity[1] and entities/entity[3] had the following errors....

Comment: The response must also be in XML format, and the consumer should be able to easily detect which entities had errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my chosen solution:

The response will be similar to the request, meaning that it will contain the same entities structure, but will only return those entities which generated errors and the errors will be appended to the original entity node.

```
<entities>
  <entity>
    <title>first</title>
    <description>short text</description>
  </entity>
  <errors>
    <error>first error</error>
    <error>second error</error>
  </errors>
</entities>
```